# ¿Como obtener el ID generado automáticamente en un proceso almacenado?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Estoy creando un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL.

Tengo dos tablas, 1. `blog` y 2. `notificacion`. La tabla `notificacion` tiene una llave foránea que es el id de blog.

¿Como puedo hacer para que ese id que se agrega automáticamente (`auto_increment`) en la tabla `blog` se agregue también a la tabla `notificacion`?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE agregar (IN fechaAdd DATE, IN autorAdd CHAR(30), IN tituloAdd CHAR(30), IN contenidoAdd TEXT)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO blog (fecha, autor, titulo, contenido) VALUES (fechaAdd, autorAdd, tituloAdd, contenidoAdd);
INSERT INTO notificacion (fecha, notificacion) VALUES (fechaAdd, 'Registro Exitoso');
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL agregar ('2021-02-16', 'David', 'MySql', 'Procedimientos');
```

Al llamar el procedimiento agrego los datos para guardarlos en la tabla, pero el id automático queda en la tabla `blog` y no en `notificacion`. Les agradezco su ayuda.

Tabla Blog

```
CREATE TABLE blog(
id_blog int not null auto_increment,
fecha date,
autor char(30),
titulo char (30),
contenido text,
primary key (id_blog)
);
```

Tabla Notificacion

```
CREATE TABLE notificacion(
id int not null auto_increment,
id_blog int,
fecha date,
notificacion char(20),
foreign key(id_blog) references blog (id_blog),
primary key (id)
);
```

Comment: Listo, agregadas las tablas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el `id` auto-generado tras el último `INSERT`, podes llamar a la función [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

> Sin argumento, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` devuelve un valor de 64 bits que representa el primer valor generado automáticamente insertado correctamente para una columna `AUTO_INCREMENT` como resultado de la instrucción `INSERT` ejecutada más recientemente. El valor de `LAST_INSERT_ID()` permanece sin cambios si no se insertan filas correctamente.
>
> Con un argumento, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` devuelve un entero sin signo.

#### Ejemplo:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE agregar (IN fechaAdd DATE, IN autorAdd CHAR(30), IN tituloAdd CHAR(30), IN contenidoAdd TEXT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE id INT;

    INSERT INTO blog (fecha, autor, titulo, contenido) VALUES (fechaAdd, autorAdd, tituloAdd, contenidoAdd);

    SET id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO notificacion (id_blog, fecha, notificacion) VALUES (id, fechaAdd, 'Registro Exitoso');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Mil gracias, ha funcionado perfecto.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes hacer es insertar el blog, para después obtener el id_blog del nuevo registro que estás insertando, después de eso lo podrás insertar en la notificación.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE agregar (IN fechaAdd DATE, IN autorAdd CHAR(30), IN 
tituloAdd CHAR(30), IN contenidoAdd TEXT)
BEGIN
declare ultimo_id_blog int;

-- Primero insertas el blog
INSERT INTO blog (fecha, autor, titulo, contenido) VALUES (fechaAdd, 
autorAdd, tituloAdd, contenidoAdd);

-- Obtenemos el id_blog del registro que cabamos de insertar
select id_blog into ultimo_id_blog from blog  order by id_blog desc limit 1;

-- Insertamos el id_blog
INSERT INTO notificacion (id_blog,fecha, notificacion) VALUES 
(ultimo_id_blog,fechaAdd, 'Registro Exitoso');
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL agregar ('2021-02-16', 'David', 'MySql', 'Procedimientos');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Colonel, ha funcionado de maravilla.